# Django auto slug in Model Forms

Tags: javascript, django, django-models, django-forms, slug

Hi there I'm trying to achieve the auto slug function via JS in my form, and following is my code.

My model:

```
class Sponsor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150)
```

My form:

```
class SponsorForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Sponsor
        fields = ['name', 'slug', 'image', 'phone', 'website', 'address', 'city', 'state', ]
        exclude = ('created_by', )
```

As you can see, I want to show the slug field to the user and he can edit it, but before edit I would like to set my slug automatically based on what he is typing in field "name". In Admin is like that.

Searching on internet, I found that Django core has this file: **urlify.js** , what is awesome. What I have done so far is:

```
<script src="{% static "js/urlify.js"%}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
    $( "#id_name" ).keyup(function() {
        $("#id_slug").val(URLify($("#id_name").value, 150));
    });
});
</script>
```

All I get are these erros in console

Error 1:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression:
>   /�|O|U|o|u|a|?|d|e|p|s|t|f|G|T|S|F|i|I|g|A|c|n|r|C|D|E|N|R|l|z|L|Z|k|K/:
>   Nothing to repeat

Error 2:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Any help or ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What this amounts to is trusting the client (i.e. allowing the browser to submit a field over which you have no control), which is never a good idea. This means a malicious user could bypass your code and pass any value in for the slug of your model, which is unlikely to be desired behavior.

Instead, do this on the server: Override the model's `save(...)` method to first [set the slug](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.text) on your model based on its name and then continue the normal save method via `super` to pass execution back to Django.

Comment: Thanks! Hope it helped. :)